# Could not retrieve transport type data for Receive Location

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I am getting the following error while starting or stopping any of the orchestration.

`Could not retrieve transport type data for Receive Location 'Receive Location2' from config store. Both SSO Servers (Primary='' and Backup='') failed. Backup server failure: Cannot perform encryption or decryption because the secret is not available from the master secret server. See the event log (on computer '**') for related errors. (Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM)`

I have changed the service account of the SSO service. Please tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

After a long time of googling finally I got the problem resolved. The steps I followed are as follows:

Go To SSO Adminnistration -> System -> Restore Secret and select the secret file.

If you dont know the path of the secret file try once in the location "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On".

Select the file and provide the password. Once the master secret restores the error will not come.